# Grid (col-xs) bootstrap 4: 2 ou 3 colunas?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia pessoal, existem alguns grids em PSD para mobile ( col-xs ) com 2 colunas e alguns com exemplos de 3 colunas. Alguém sabe o porque dessa diferença? Teria algum grid mobile em PSD ou sketch para compartilhar conosco?

Desde já muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falo por experiência própria que, muitas vezes, as pessoas vão querer algo mais minimalista. Tanto de 2 colunas, quanto 3, são minimalistas, porque não "enche" de informações numa única linha. Na minha opinião, prefiro que seja de 2 colunas, porque torna o site mais rapidamente legível, mais "limpo" e formatado, ainda mais para a versão mobile, já que quase tudo hoje se acessa por celular.

Comment: Muito obrigado Gabriel. Ouvi dizer que no grid xs poderíamos até ter 5 colunas, procede isso? Você teria algum psd ou sketch com uma grid xs de 3 colunas que estivesse em conformidade com o bootstrap 4?

Comment: Na verdade, tu é livre pra escolher quantas colunas tu quiser, se quiser colocar 12 colunas, tu consegue (nesse caso, adicionando 12 vezes o `div class="col-xs-1"` no código HTML). Então dá pra colocar bem tranquilo as 5 colunas. E não conheço nenhum PSD/sketch de 3 colunas, mas com certeza deve ter um por aí.